# Print ASCII histogram

Tags: code-golf

The challenge is to give as short code as possible to print an ASCII histogram of a set of data.

**Input.**  The number of bins followed by a number of integers representing the data. The data are space separated.

**Output.** An ASCII histogram of the data using the specified number of bins.

**Score.** Number of characters in the code excluding trailing whitespace at the beginning or end of each line.

Example input.

```
2    2    3    4    2    2    5
```

Example output.

```
*
*
**
**
```

**Update.** The answers are all great although I can only ever imagine using the one in **R**.  No python contribution?

Comment: What is the relation between your input and output?

Comment: I think the first value of the input is the number of bins and all the others the vector to proceed: if you split it into two bins of equal size, the first one contains 4 values (three 2s and one 3) and the second 2 values (a 4 and a 5).

Comment: @plannapus. That's right. Thanks.

Comment: Related to an oldie on Stack Overflow: [Code golf: Word frequency chart](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3169051/2509).

Comment: Are the bin sizes integers also. If so what answer do you get for: 4 1 1 2 2 5 8 9 6 3

Comment: @Graham I had only thought about the integer sizes! For case you give it would ideally do something sensible although I didn't define it.

Comment: @Majid I note your update but from the site FAQ "Code golf is a special type of programming puzzle where the shortest correct code submission wins." You have selected the longest!

Comment: @Graham You are 100% right. I should have specified in the question that I would award to a "sensible" language.

Comment: See also this similar question on reddit: [\[2017-02-08\] Challenge #302 \[Intermediate\] ASCII Histogram Maker: Part 1 - The Simple Bar Chart](https://www.reddit.com/r/dailyprogrammer/comments/5st2so/20170208_challenge_302_intermediate_ascii/)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### APL <s>66</s> 51

```
' *'[1+(⌽⍳b)∘.≤v←+/(⍳b)∘.=⌈x[⍋x]÷(⌈/x←1↓v)÷b←↑v←⍎⍞]
```

Using the example I quoted in my comment on the question where the bin size is 2.25:

```
4 1 1 2 2 5 8 9 6 3

*
*
* **
****
```

Comment: How can you run it at [tryapl.org](http://www.tryapl.org/)? It gives me `invalid token` error in the ways I tried.

Comment: I can very rarely get that to work. If you want to play around with APL then I suggest you download the free interpreter from here: http://www.nars2000.org/

Comment: @Graham How do you even type that line on a normal keyboard?

Comment: You don't without an APL interpreter. If you download the interpreter I suggested above you can then either use a keyboard map to type the APL, use the on screen point and click APL keyboard or simply copy and paste from this page.

Answer (score 3):

#### GolfScript, <strike>57</strike> <strike>55</strike> 52 characters

```
~](\$:?;:b,{{\?0=-b*?)\0=-)/=" *"=}+?%$}%zip{32-},n*
```

Taking input as single line from STDIN. Script can be tested [online](http://golfscript.apphb.com/?c=OyI0IDEgMSAyIDIgNSA4IDYgMyIKCn5dKFwkOj87OmIse3tcPzA9LWIqPylcMD0tKS89IiAqIj19Kz8lJH0lemlwezMyLX0sbio%3D&run=true).

Example:

```
> 4 1 1 2 2 5 8 6 3
*   
*   
* * 
****
```

Comment: Following on from my comment on the question what bin size does your code give for an input of: 4 1 1 2 2 5 8 9 6 3 and are you happy with the ASCII result?

Answer (score 2):

### J, <s>96</s> 86

```
(' *'{~|.@|:@(>/i.@(>./))@(}:@}:,{:@}:+{:)@(+/@(=/i.@>:@{.)~<.@({.*(%>./)@(-<./)@}.)))
```

In a little more readable format: http://pastebin.com/2CiaJXjC.

```
   (...) 2 2 3 4 2 2 5
* 
* 
**
**
   (...) 4 1 1 2 2 5 8 6 3
*   
*   
* * 
****
```

Step by step on example values: http://pastebin.com/nXjGcq8L.

Answer (score 1):

### R - <s>133</s> 122 characters

```
a=scan()
b=table(cut(a[-1],a[1]))
invisible(apply(cbind(sapply(b,function(x)c(rep(" ",max(b)-x),rep("*",x))),"\n"),1,cat))
```

When sourced, it prompts the user for input (because of `scan`), and output the ascii histogram.

```
> source('asciihist.R')
1: 2 2 3 4 5 2 2 5
9: 
Read 8 items
*   
* * 
* * 
* * 

> source('asciihist.R')
1: 4 1 1 2 2 5 8 6 3
10: 
Read 9 items
*       
*       
*   *   
* * * *
```

Comment: Due to vector recycling, you could replace `rep("\n",d)` with `"\n"`. This would save 7 characters.

Comment: @SvenHohenstein Better than that actually: I don't need to declare `d` anymore! Thanks!

Comment: I accepted this one as it is in a language I might possibly use. Apologies to the other great entries.

Comment: I unaccepted as I see I wasn't following the house rules. Sorry.